# Каким образом выводить по 3 статьи в блоке, в цикле

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. 
Вывожу статьи на сайте с помощью цикла:

```
$last_news = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    while ($lnews = mysql_fetch_assoc($last_news)) {

 //разметка

}
```

Мне нужно чтоб на странице получилась такая разметка

```
<div id="r_block">
    тут три статьи
</div>

<div id="r_block">
    тут три статьи
</div>

<div id="r_block">
    тут три статьи
</div>
```

И каждый раз чтоб было по 3 статьи в блоке **r_block**

Каким образом реализовать это в моем цикле? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считайте выводимые статьи и по остаткам от деления номера строки на 3 расставляйте требуемую разметку. Как то так:

```
$last_news = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$num=0;
while ($lnews = mysql_fetch_assoc($last_news)) {
   if($num % 3 == 0) { echo '<div id="r_block">'; }

   //разметка

   if($num % 3 == 2) { echo '</div>'; }
   $num++;
}
if($num % 3 != 0) { echo '</div>'; }
```

Comment: спасибо большое. сейчас реализую себе и приму ответ

Comment: @Денис я бы посмотрел на ответ ниже ипатьева, а этому ответу минус за кастыли и за лень, скобочки надо ставить скобочки. А то всё больше людей пишет на PHP как на js плевать на скобочки да и лучше так `?:` писать чё это три символа целых, и т.д.

Comment: @Naumov Не понял, вы про какие скобки, после echo, что бы на функцию было похоже ... Это да - можно. Или вы что то другое имеете ввиду ?

Comment: @Naumov И да, конечно я видел ответ Ипатьева. И лично мне не нравится современный стиль PHP в котором из за кучи тегов не видно кода программы. Отладка чужого кода становится невыносимой.

Comment: @Mike Что? теги вы только что их выводите в `echo`, скобки фигурные `{}`. и вообще лучше не мешать логику и представление. Сейчас сервера дешёвые и мощные а интерпритаторы быстрее, допустим тот же php7 на котором это решение не будет работать, плюс есть куча способов кэширования и серверной реализации функций сайта написанных на C++ и работающих в разы быстрее. Так что выбирать стоит из соотношение скоррости и надёжности и лёгкости поддержки. серверные решения например поиск `sphinx`, кэшь `varnish` и т.д.

Comment: @Naumov Я то же за то что бы не мешать. для этого есть шаблонизаторы. Вот если бы у ТС они были бы - то и ответ был бы совсем иным и в коде не было бы HTML. А использовать голый php как шаблонизатор я не любитель. Очень жаль, что сообщество минусует рабочий код за стиль оформления, который дело вкуса в общем то

Comment: @Mike не принимайте минусы ответа на свой счёт, я заминусовал не только за стиль оформления а за велосипед, вы только что описали на php `array_chunk` надо всё таки, давать сподвишки к изучению нативного функционала а не велосипедостроительству, вы уж простите.

Answer (score 6):

1. Вместо mysql_query следует использовать PDO
2. Вместо вывода прямо на месте, следует использовать шаблон.

Поэтому делаем так:

сначала получаем нужные данные в массив

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 15";
$last_news = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();
```

затем разбиваем этот массив на куски по три строки

```
$out = array_chunk($last_news, 3);
```

и в заключение выводим в шаблоне

```
<?php foreach($out as $chunk): ?>
    <div id="r_block">
        <?php foreach($chunk as $row): ?>
            <div>
                <a href="<?=$row['url']?>"><?=$row['title']?></a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Подход же, описанный в другом ответе, применялся в прошлом веке, когда никто не умел писать на РНР. А сейчас так писать, перемешивая работу с БД, HTML и на пальцах высчитывая сколько строк вывести каждый раз - это в очередной раз подтверждать репутацию РНР, как убогого, презираемого всеми языка. Не надо так делать.

Comment: Полностью согласен, разве что `array_chunk($last_news, 3)` можно прямо в foreach запихнуть.

Comment: Изящное решение!

Comment: @ZhukovRoman Зачем он там усложнить чтение и дебагинг, так ты просто поставил точку остановки на переменной `$out` и видишь массив в xdebug и idea...

Comment: :o_O кто то ещё такие ответы минусует, парни наберитесь смелости за что минус? или что только на кнопочки жать умеете?

Comment: @Naumov зачем там дебаггинг?

Comment: @ZhukovRoman да если так разобраться да зачем он вообще нужен... да и там в ответе разделенно просто foreach в шаблоне а переменная где то в логике.

Answer (score 3):

Короче можете заминусоват, за то что я  публикую опровержения ответа @Mike в поддержку @Ипатьева...

Но всё же я это сделаю...

и так рассмотрим функцию `array_chunk`

```
/* {{{ proto array array_chunk(array input, int size [, bool preserve_keys])
   Split array into chunks */
PHP_FUNCTION(array_chunk)
{
    int argc = ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), num_in;
    zend_long size, current = 0;
    zend_string *str_key;
    zend_ulong num_key;
    zend_bool preserve_keys = 0;
    zval *input = NULL;
    zval chunk;
    zval *entry;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(argc, "al|b", &input, &size, &preserve_keys) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }
    /* Do bounds checking for size parameter. */
    if (size < 1) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Size parameter expected to be greater than 0");
        return;
    }

    num_in = zend_hash_num_elements(Z_ARRVAL_P(input));

    if (size > num_in) {
        size = num_in > 0 ? num_in : 1;
    }

    array_init_size(return_value, (uint32_t)(((num_in - 1) / size) + 1));

    ZVAL_UNDEF(&chunk);

    ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_KEY_VAL(Z_ARRVAL_P(input), num_key, str_key, entry) {
        /* If new chunk, create and initialize it. */
        if (Z_TYPE(chunk) == IS_UNDEF) {
            array_init_size(&chunk, (uint32_t)size);
        }

        /* Add entry to the chunk, preserving keys if necessary. */
        if (preserve_keys) {
            if (str_key) {
                entry = zend_hash_update(Z_ARRVAL(chunk), str_key, entry);
            } else {
                entry = zend_hash_index_update(Z_ARRVAL(chunk), num_key, entry);
            }
        } else {
            entry = zend_hash_next_index_insert(Z_ARRVAL(chunk), entry);
        }
        zval_add_ref(entry);

        /* If reached the chunk size, add it to the result array, and reset the
         * pointer. */
        if (!(++current % size)) {
            add_next_index_zval(return_value, &chunk);
            ZVAL_UNDEF(&chunk);
        }
    } ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_END();

    /* Add the final chunk if there is one. */
    if (Z_TYPE(chunk) != IS_UNDEF) {
        add_next_index_zval(return_value, &chunk);
    }
}
```

И так обратим внимание на строчку

```
/* If reached the chunk size, add it to the result array, and reset the
 * pointer. */
if (!(++current % size)) {
    add_next_index_zval(return_value, &chunk);
    ZVAL_UNDEF(&chunk);
}
```

Что она нам говорит? правильно то же самое что и в ответе высчитываем остаток от деления на этот самый размер и добавляем в `return_value` получившийся `chunk` заметте `chunk` это ссылка т.е. физически это одна переменная. При том что этот код более оптимизирован так как он:

1. Скомпилирован
2. Он типизирован (тут нету этапа приведения типов и т.д. и т.п.)
3. Создаётся хэш размером от самого нужный длинны без запаса (для старых версий php может быть и другая реализация)

т.е. по сути мы видим что ответ майка чуть менее чем полностью реализует функционал `array_chunk` да и по скорости и по потреблению памяти они будут сравнимы, в определённых относительных плоскостях.

p.s. @Mike так что не вижу причины писать 'не красиво' ради сомнительной оптимизации.

источник кода: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/bd9858ead26f2b1537ca61f3f5a136f8ec160a27/ext/standard/array.c

p.p.s. Ну и малость аргументов за кодинг стаил

простой пример

```
 if($num % 3 == 2) echo '</div>';
   $num++;
```

нет ошибок всё хорошо.

```
  if($num % 3 == 2) // echo '</div>';
       $num++;
```

ошибок нет, но алгоритм не работает.

более распространённый пример

```
// тут сотня строк подобного кода
if($b == 2) $a = 2;
$a=1;
// ну и тут так же
```

хороший пример видел в кодинг стайле для си написания условий

```
if(2 == $a) {}
```

круто да опечатался так `if(2=$a)` а тебе ошибка.
а если расмотреть как мы пишем

```
if($a == 2) {}
```

а если опечатался `if($a=2)` то уже `$a` равно 2-м, ошибок нет алгоритм не рабочий.

p.p.s. Всё же считаю что надо писать красиво и что бы работало, при том в сообществе где помагают, что бы у junior'а не спрашивал темлид `а где ты вот этот кусочек откапал кода?`

Comment: Согласен со всем кроме "по скорости и по потреблению памяти они будут сравнимы". На небольших массивах (в свойм ответе Ипатьев ограничил выборку всего 15ю элементами, в случае статей это вполне логично) это действительно так (удвоенное потребление памяти, скорее всего, будет не заметно, на фоне всего остального). Но на больших массивах код Ипатьева может упасть по памяти или продолжительности исполнения (материализованные данные весят намного больше результата запроса (покрайней мере в mysql и mysqli), а аллокации которые происходят в array_chunk могут требовать довольно много времени).

Answer (score -2):

```
$i = 1;
echo( '<div id="r_block">' );
while ($lnews = mysql_fetch_assoc($last_news)) {
    //разметка
    if ( $i == 3 ) {
        echo( '</div><div id="r_block">' );
        $i = 1;
    }
    else {
        $i++;
    }
}
echo( '</div>' );
```

Comment: Найдите баг в своём коде? и поймете почему минус...

Comment: Буду благодарен если скажите где баг.

Comment: @Zim так в том и сложность что вы даже своё решение не можете прочитать, и найти в нём ошибку, проще надо писать чтобы было с первого взгляда видно что не так...

Comment: Хорошо, я не смыслю в php. Но хочу узнать где баг, вам же не сложно.

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade не будьте так категоричны, и не грубите человеку,это его право отвечать или не отвечать

Comment: @Zim прочитайте свой код что он выведет?

Comment: @Naumov,  будет выводить //разметка по 3 раза внутри <div id="r_block">

Comment: @Naumov, баг в лишнем выводе пустого <div id="r_block"> если есть всего 3 статьи?

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade, для этого есть сообщество которое укажет на проблему, а не пошлет подальше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43416/discussion-between-zim-and-naumov).